# My question have to be so Formal?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

In my question I don't understand why some users keep editing for a more formal way [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793239/stopwatch-equivalent-in-php).

I made it "informal" on purpose. Did I do it wrong? I rollback to my version and received a "rollback" in my face again **>.<**

Comment: I even received a close vote o.O ... uau O.o

Comment: Yes, I just had that question in the close queue and voted to close as off-topic with the subreason: finding off-site resource. It is either that or too broad...

Comment: @rene I got an answer, as I was looking for. Since there are TONS of questions asking how to do a function X in another language. I didn't even knew if that was possible. I don't think you vote right on this.

Comment: Ok, I'll consider your point of view the next time I close vote a question.

Comment: wow... nowadays people on SO is getting really "strict".

Comment: @MichelAyres More like it used to be really strict and now you only see rare occasions like this where people still try to maintain the strictness.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, your questions need to be "formal."

Affectations like *"sweet-stuff that you may desire :)"* and decorations like smiley faces and frowny faces are just noise, and don't add any semantic detail to your question that will assist us in answering it.

Comment: T_T ok, I understand :(

Comment: Must... resist... urge... to... call... Robert... sweet-cheeks...